# here i had used datepicker dialog to display date in textfield but unable to change format as well as remove time from displaying

Tags: ios, swift3

here i had used [DatePickerDialog](https://github.com/squimer/DatePickerDialog-iOS-Swift) for displaying the date but i am unable to remove the time from the textfield and unable to change time format also can anyone help me ?

```
let currentDate = Date() 
var dateComponents = DateComponents() 
dateComponents.month = -1350 
let MonthsAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: currentDate) 
DatePickerDialog().show("DatePickerDialog", doneButtonTitle: "Done", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", minimumDate: MonthsAgo, maximumDate: currentDate, datePickerMode: .date) 
{ (date) in if let dt = date { self.dobTextField.text = "(dt)" } }
```

Comment: link not working.

Comment: https://github.com/squimer/DatePickerDialog-iOS-Swift

Comment: chnage the dateformat before assign to textfield

Comment: let currentDate = Date()
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.month = -1350
        let MonthsAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: currentDate)
        DatePickerDialog().show("DatePickerDialog", doneButtonTitle: "Done", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", minimumDate: MonthsAgo, maximumDate: currentDate, datePickerMode: .date) { (date) in
            if let dt = date {
                self.dobTextField.text = "\(dt)"
            }
        }

Comment: where i need to add it this was my code @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: what the output you get here `dt` and what the OP you need

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6dER.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatePickerDialog().show("DatePickerDialog", doneButtonTitle: "Done", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", minimumDate: threeMonthAgo, maximumDate: currentDate, datePickerMode: .date) { (date) in
            if let dt = date {
                 let formatter = DateFormatter()
                  formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy" // change format as per your needs
                  self.textField.text = formatter.string(from:dt)
            }
        }
```

Comment: how do you know  `dt` dateformat, your answer need a modification based on `dt` dateformat else your answer not work